# How to set NDK on android studio after downloading it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

For some odd reason I'm unable to set Android NDK location, I download it and now I'm unable to set the location. The button is disabled and really don't know what to do. Is it possible to set the location using the command line on MacOS?

[image: NDK Location]

[image: Disable Button]

Comment: How did you download it? You could have downloaded it from the sdk manager on android studio itself. If you wanna do it manually, you can set it in the file called `local.properties` like this `ndk.dir=<ndkPath>`

Comment: All I did, was hit the `Download` Android NDK

Comment: Yeah, but from where? Did you try doing it using the SDK Manager?

Comment: Here what I did, `File->Project Structure->SDK Location` I didn't use sdk manager

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but it was on windows, the button for setting ndk location was disabled and  I solved it by adding

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\24.0.8215888
```

in local.properties and I syncing it. The last part (24.0.8215888) might be different for you depending on the installed ndk version.

Answer (score 0):

Android->local.properties and add ndk version

> Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\ndkversion

for mac users -

/Users/starka/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888

In order to download desired ndk version in android studio, go to tools->sdk manager->sdk tools (enable show package details) -> NDK and download the desired version.